# Android SQL Update statement

Tags: android, sql, sql-update

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this SQL Update statement please?

```
SQLiteDatabase hashDB = openOrCreateDatabase(HASH_DB, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

hashDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + HASH_TABLE1 + " (FileName VARCHAR, Hash VARCHAR);");


ContentValues updateFilesTable = new ContentValues();
updateFilesTable.put("Hash", hash);
hashDB.update(HASH_TABLE1, updateFilesTable, "FileName" + "=" + file, null);
```

`file` and `hash` are both Strings and I know they have the correct data in them, the records I am trying to update definitely exist in the database. `HASH_TABLE1` also points to the correct table.

Many Thanks

Matt

Comment: Consider using prepared statements. This avoids all the problems with escaping, possible SQL injection (that's rather something for web applications) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't quoting the file string.  You want this line to read:

```
hashDB.update(HASH_TABLE1, updateFilesTable, "FileName = ?", new String[] { file });
```